# I have very wide table and my css is getting massed on overflowed parts

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

My English is not so good. Sorry for bad grammer from now.

I have a very wide table with 21 fields. This columns doesnt fit to a full page. So i made it with overflow: scroll. When page loads, there is no problem. But when i scroll it right, my css doesnt work as it should. For example; hover events doenst work well and cant see box shadows, background colors.

Also my first column is sticky to left. And it works well when scrolling. But when it comes to right border, it goes left and disappear. It's just like my page ends horizontally at right, but i think it should scroll fine.

[image: This is first time it opens]

[image: This is when i scroll it right]

[image: This is how it happens when i scroll more, left sticky part is going.]

```js
class Employees extends Component {
  componentWillMount = () => {
    this.props.getEmployees()
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div className="page">
        <TopNavbar>
          <NavButton>Ekle</NavButton>
          <NavButton>Sil</NavButton>
          <NavButton>Güncelle</NavButton>
          <NavButton>Excell'den Aktar</NavButton>
          <NavButton>Excell'e Aktar</NavButton>
        </TopNavbar>
        <div className="page-content">
          <Employee
            employee={{
              domain: 'Domain',
              email: 'E-posta',
              sicilNo: 'Sicil No',
              fullName: 'Adı',
              company: 'Şirket',
              jobLocation: 'İş Yeri',
              jobStartDate: 'İş Başlangıç Tarihi',
              groupStartDate: 'Grup Başlangıç Tarihi',
              duty: 'Görev',
              unvan: 'ünvan',
              manager: 'Yönetici',
              medeniDurum: 'Medeni Durum',
              children: 'Çocuk Sayısı',
              breakpoint1: 'Kırılım 1',
              breakpoint2: 'Kırılım 2',
              breakpoint3: 'Kırılım 3',
              breakpoint4: 'Kırılım 4',
              breakpoint5: 'Kırılım 5',
              breakpoint6: 'Kırılım 6',
              breakpoint7: 'Kırılım 7',
              isFlexChosen: 'Seçim Yapıldı'
            }}
            sticky=" sticky"
            header={true}
          />
          {this.props.employees.map((employee, index) => (
            <Employee key={index.toString()} employee={employee} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```css
.side-navbar {
  background: $primary;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 15vw;
}


.page {
  width: 85vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

App.js contains side-navbar and page, they are 15vw and 85vw. page class is overflow: hidden. Inside page class, i have page-content and its width: '100%'. Every content is in page-content and page-content is overflow: scroll. By the way, these are not table,tr,td elements. I dont like tables. They are all flexboxes. And yes, i tried it with tables, result is the same.

Comment: Hey Furkan, add some code...

Comment: Where does the box-shadow come from? I don't see any css relating to that

Comment: Can you please post your rendered HTML? The react code doesn't really help. Give us a few lines of your table.

Comment: Sorry i deleted it. But you can see table headers have shadows until right border.